# Which payment gateways allow for marketplace?

Tags: ecommerce

I am trying to create an app which allows various people to buy from various vendors. I am now researching for payment gateways, and from what my research has shown, the marketplace functionality is an important one to implement this kind of service, I'd like to know which gateways provide this.

Comment: What are your requirements? Please read [ask]